# Is anyone aware of an UI that i can reuse/fork for some CRUD operations on nosql database

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, nosql, aws-documentdb

I have a basic nosql document database with less than 50 entries. Lately I've been making lots of little updates on others behalf on the documents.
The changes themselves are minor and straight forward.
I would like to allow my friends and colleagues to perform CRUD operations on the db, through an UI.

But i do not want to spend anytime writing the UI that i can use in front of a crud api.

Is anyone aware an UI tool i can use or a repo that I can fork that would give me an UI "for free", which would help in

- displaying the document
- and updating any changes to the document.

So, not even fully CRUD for the first pass

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Amazon DocumentDB as the nosql document database, then, because is compatible with MongoDB, you can use any GUI client available. Some of the more popular ones are [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass), [Studio3t](https://studio3t.com/free/) or [Nosqlbooster](https://nosqlbooster.com/downloads)